# error 1041 in event viewer

Tags: windows-xp, event-viewer

I get such error in Event viewer 1041, Userenv
Details:

```
Windows cannot query DllName registry entry for {7B849a69-220F-451E-B3FE-2CB811AF94AE} and it will not be loaded. This is most likely caused by a faulty registration.
```

What could case it and how to fix? Maybe some addition information is needed just tell me what exactly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have IE8 beta installed?
Entry: 7B849a69-220F-451E-B3FE-2CB811AF94AE. Windows 2003 R2 32-bit Terminal Server.Release version of IE8 had previously been installed and then uninstalled. After the IE uninstall errors began appearing in the Application event log. From a TechArena forum post 
[Link](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-xp-support/1036331.htm)
, I resolved the problem using the suggested method of searching + deleting registry entries. I had two class numbers that were registering this error message. Both class numbers were located in the registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\GPExtensions{respective class number here}

Comment: There is no link :)

Comment: thank you I delete 7B849a69-220F-451E-B3FE-2CB811AF94AE in regestry and errors disappeared